# htlatex with greek encoding

Tags: greek, htlatex

I used `htlatex` to the following code (say foo.tex)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multibib}

\begin{document}

αβγδ 
{\it αβγδ}

\end{document}
```

I execute

`mk4ht htlatex foo.tex "xhtml,mathml"`

and the html file gave me the following
`αβγδ abgd`

I would expect 
`αβγδ *αβγδ*`

That is can not translate right the `\it` with the greek characters.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by how `tex4ht` process fonts - special conversion files for each used font is used. This file is obviously missing for Greek italics. Simple solution is to disable italics font with `tex4ht`.

First of all, you should edit your source file and use

```
\textit{αβγδ}
```

instead of

```
{\it αβγδ}
```

because this form cannot be easily converted to html with this technique.

Then create custom config file `config.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml, mathml}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\textit[1]{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\NoFonts\HCode{<em>}#1\HCode{</em>}\EndNoFonts}
\EndPreamble
```

This configuration will prevent usage of italics font and will insert `<em>` tags.

Compile with:

```
htlatex  foo.tex "config, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

Result:

```
<p class="noindent" >αβγδ <em>αβγδ</em>                                                              
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Almost work, I got the following, `<p class="noindent" >abgd <em>abgd</em>`. I found that htlatex give an error `couldn't find font grmn1000.htf char:0--255`

Comment: Finally, the following work, `htlatex  foo.tex "config, charset=utf-8" `